# How to convert video on s3 using python without download it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have bunch of videos in my s3 bucket and i want to convert their format using python but Currently I'm stuck at one issue. My python script for fetching all objects of bucket is as below.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
            region_name = S3_REGION,
            aws_access_key_id = S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
            aws_secret_access_key = S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
        result = s3.list_objects(Bucket = bucket_name, Prefix='videos/')
        for o in result.get('Contents'):
            data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=o.get('Key'))
```

And for conversion of video format i have used MoviePy library which convert video format to mp4

```
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("video-529.webm")
clip.write_videofile("converted-recording.mp4")
```

But problem with this library is it need a file only you can not pass s3 object as a file so i don't know how to overcome this issue if anyone have better idea for this then please help me ? How to resolve this ?.

Comment: S3 is just big, dumb storage.  It can't execute anything.  You'll have to download, convert, and upload.

Comment: There are some AWS services you can use to convert, transform, etc within AWS, so you don't have to download them. One example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/on-the-fly-video-conversion-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-mediaconvert/

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Libraries require the video file to be on the 'local disk', so you should use `download_file()` instead of `get_object()`.

Alternatively, you could use [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html) to transcode the file 'as a service' rather than doing it in your own code. (Charges apply, based on video length.)